# Problema com scanf em %d recebendo uma letra do teclado

Tags: c, char, scanf

Estou com um problema, estou lendo um `int %d` pelo `scanf`, mas se o usuário digita uma letra o programa entra em *loop*.

```
void chama_menu_switch(Fila **f, int n){

char confi;
int i,y,x,a,z;
double r;
a = 0;
int b;
for (i = 0; z != 11; i++) { // inicio for

printf("|*|Comandos Menu 1.0|*|\n1 - Criar nova coluna\n2 - Deletar uma coluna\n3 - Inserir receita em coluna\n4 - Remover receita em coluna\n5 - Visualizar lista de colunas\n6 - Remover despesa em coluna\n7 - Inserir despesa em coluna\n8 - Visualiza despesas em uma coluna\n9 - Visualiza receitas em uma coluna\n10 - Calcular lucro bruto\n11 - Sair\n");
    //_flushall();
b = scanf("%d%*c",&z);
    __fpurge(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (b == 0) {
        printf("entro");
        system("pause");
        scanf(" %d",&b);
    }
```

Fiz um mini menu usando `switch` no console.. ta funcionando normalmente, o default do `switch` percebe que não esta nos casos e da *break*, porem ele ignora o `scanf` e entra em *loop*.

Answer (score 1):

Eu estruturava meus menus mais ou menos dessa maneira amigo

```
int opcao;

do{
    printf("1- Opcao 1 \n2- Opcao 2 \n0- Sair");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    switch(opcao){
        case 1: printf("Opcao 1"); break;
        case 2: printf("Opcao 2"); break;
    }
}while(opcao != 0)
```

Comment: Felipe , estou usando um for por que estou passando valores das somas pra u vetor de ponteiros pra umas estruturas.. mas de qualquer jeito se eu usasse um do while se o usuário digitar uma letra no seu int vai crashar.. um amigo meu achou a solução vou postar aqui caso outras pessoas busquem a mesma duvida, muito obrigado.

Comment: Outra solução era usando um char como opcao, nesse caso nao crasharia.

Comment: Exato, fiz quase isso.. passei pra um char e dps converti pra int.. fiz uma macumba aqui, não sei se é o mais pratico, talvez se eu tivesse feito tudo do inicio por char teria dado menos dor de cabeça, mas pra mudar agora pra tudo char ia me ferrar. Segue a função: http://pastebin.com/fHPV880q

Comment: Haha, concordo, deveria ter feito tudo com char '~'